# Methods for splitting a dataset efficiently

Tags: validation, machine-learning, dataset, training-data

I have a fairly large dataset of images. They have been taken by 'x' number of photographers and each image falls into one of 'y' themes. How would I go about making a train, valid, test split if I want no photographer overlap between the splits and as minimal theme overlap as possible(i.e. theme overlap between valid and train is okay but not with test)?

Some themes are not captured by some photographers. I've tried first splitting the set by photographers and then try to combine these with minimal theme overlap but there's a lot of trial and error and I was wondering if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `train_test_split` function inside `scikit-learn` library to split your dataset into `train` and `test`. like below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=42)
```

where

```
X = Features and Y = Labels
```

Then you can use `cross_validate` function that randomly takes some part of the training data as `validation` data and train it on the algorithm passed,
like below

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

cv_results = cross_validate(algorithm, x_train, y_train, cv=3)
```

This is how your test data and train data won't overlap